# Getting the newest date from 3 tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the newest date from three separate tables, each with a 'lastmodified' column. Essentially I am trying to work out when the database was last modified.

For example:

```
Table 1 -lastmodified column
Table 2 -lastmodified column
Table 3 -lastmodified column
```

I was tying the following code. I know the part where I get the individual newest record from each table is wrong but I am not entirely sure how to change it to get it right.

```
(SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES 
    (SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM IMAGES),
    (SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM VIDEOS),
    (SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM DOCUMENTS)
) AS VALUE (v)) AS MaxDate)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I know the part where I get the individual newest record from each table is wrong" Why do you think it's wrong? If `lastmodifieddate` is of type `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or `time` then your code should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UNION` to combine the records into one column from different tables then get the `MAX` out of it.

```
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) AS lastmodifieddate
FROM
(
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) AS lastmodifieddate FROM IMAGES
UNION 
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM VIDEOS
UNION
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM DOCUMENTS
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

use `union` among the the tables for combine 3 max date from 3 tables then take `max()` of that subquery

```
SELECT max(date_m) as  maxdateof3tables from
(
  select MAX(lastmodifieddate) as date_m FROM IMAGES
  union     
  SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM VIDEOS
  union
  SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM DOCUMENTS
 ) as t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate)
FROM (
SELECT lastmodifieddate from IMAGES
UNION ALL
SELECT lastmodifieddate from VIDEOS
UNION ALL
SELECT lastmodifieddate from DOCUMENTS
)T
```

Comment: This is getting the right answer, but UNION is removing duplicates.  MAX() doesn't need duplicates preemptively removed (use UNION ALL).

Comment: @Zorkolot True. From a performance point of view, UNION ALL is better. Thanks for your observation, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

You `Max` function with `Union All`

```
SELECT MAX(t) AS lastmodifieddate
FROM
(
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) AS t FROM IMAGES
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM VIDEOS
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(lastmodifieddate) FROM DOCUMENTS
) Temp
```

Comment: MAX() doesn't need to be taken multiple times.  You could just have it once in the receiving query.